# Remove first N and last M characters of a file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Let's say I have a file which contains just one row and its length may vary.

`This is an example row`

I'd like have:
`is an example`

so 4 first and 3 last characters are trimmed.

is it achievable by just running single command in sh?

Answer (score 0):

With plain POSIX `sh`, you can do something like:

```sh
myvar=$(sed -e 's/^....//' -e 's/...$//' input.txt)
```

With a more powerful shell like `bash` or `zsh`, it can be done without resorting to an external program:

```sh
myvar=$(< input.txt)
myvar=${myvar:4:-3}
```

Comment: And `ksh93` would use `${myvar:4:${#myvar}-7}`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "single command" you mean one execution (not precluding pipes).

```
cat test.txt | cut -c5- | rev | cut -c4- | rev
```

**Breakdown:**

1. Get the file's content with cat
2. Keep only the fifth character until the last character with cut
3. Reverse the order of the characters
4. Keep only the fourth character (fourth from last in your original string) until the last character
5. Reverse again

Answer (score 0):

Have the first N and last M characters trimmed *per line*:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,N+1,length-N-M)}' file
$ sed 's/^\(.\)\{,N\}//;s/\(.\)^\{,M\}$//' file
```

Have the first N and last M characters trimmed *of the file*:

```
$ awk '(FNR==1){p=substr($0,N+1);next}{print p; p=$0}END{print substr(p,1,length-M)}' file
$ awk '{p=p ORS $0}END{print substr(p,N+2,length(p)-N-M-1)}' file
$ sed '1s/^\(.\)\{,N\}//;$s/\(.\)^\{,M\}$//' file
```